# How to convert string into control characters?

Tags: javascript

We have a program where a user can input a line-break for another system.

the problem is when substituting a string with this line-break, it simply adds "\n".
for instance :

works :

```
var test = 'message';
test+='\n';
console.log("message " + test); // (doesnt show \n)
```

doesn't work :

```
var test="message";
var myLineBreakFromDatabase = getMyLineBreak();//simply returns a string containing "\n"
test+=myLineBreakFromDatabase;
```

test is now = "message\n" which is useless.

However, we using Javascript in the entire system so I guess just to figure out how to convert a line-break from string into control-characters?

Comment: what does "getMyLineBreak()" do? What database?

Comment: How do you reach the conclusion "it contains .."? `\n` is the normal way of representing a return (or else you could not *see* it).

Comment: thanks to this dumb downvoters : go and get a life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your linebreaks for different systems are stored in a database where the linebreak for unix is `\u000A` and the one for windows is `\u000D\u000A`, then you could read the text into `myLineBreak` and then do something like:

```
var actualLineBreakString=JSON.parse('"' + myLineBreak + '"');
```

You'll have to make sure your javascript has the JSON object. If needed, it can be grabbed at json.org.

This approach works for any of the special characters. See here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the string you are getting back from your database is actually something like `"\\n"`, not `"\n"`.  Most likely you have some autoescaping going on somewhere, either before things get saved in the DB or before it gets to where you are using it in your app.

Hacky workaround that isn't a great idea but will probably "work":

```
var myLineBreakFromDatabase = getMyLineBreak().split('\\n').join('\n');
```

Comment: worked, thanks. i guess i need run this for all 26 characters in order to make it work all control characters.

Comment: @mc007 if you need all the linebreak characters, check my answer.